# how to make text bold in Facebook Messenger bot

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-chatbot

I want to make some text bold in Facebook Messenger, I know adding *text* will make text bold. I have been using this before.
Look like Facebook has done some updates recently when I add (asterisk)*text*(asterisk), it repeated the first two letters of the text.

when I send a message using hero card, text with bold is coming.
When i send as
   `await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Some *text*");`

I am seeing the problem.

there is no update here also. [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/147348452522644)

[image]

Comment: whats wrong in my question. Why -1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Some **text**")?

Here you can see more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cconnector-html

Comment: Thanks for ur response. It seems there is an issue with Facebook. I have raised the incident with facebook. I will give update soon.